# config-yargs not found with webpack4 and webpack-cli installed

Tags: typescript, webpack, vue.js

After creating a new VueJS Project (with TypeScript, ans Single Files Components class) I get an error when launching it with npm run dev. I've seen on differents topics that you need to have webpack-cli installed, so I installed it, but i still get the same error :

```
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/bin/config-yargs'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\tozenda\Documents\SEC\testlearning\learning\ElectriCar.WebSite\electricar.website\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:54:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

Here is part of my package.json :

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src",
    "build": "node build/build.js"},
[...]
"devDependencies": {
    [...]
    "webpack": "^4.16.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
```

Do you have a solution ?

Thank you

UPDATE : I tried to downgrade to webpack 3.12.0, but ts-loader asks for webpack 4...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION :

As npm update does not updates ALL the packages, this was the problem.

I used `npm-update-all` to update all the packages. This solved my problem.